# Вызов функции после закрытия окна

Tags: javascript, dom

Имеется окно загрузки файла, которое вызывается с помощью input'а. При нажатии, всплывает окно проводника. Нужно отследить событие, когда пользователь закрыл окно.

```
<input type="file" id="uploadfile" />
```

Как с помощью javascript отследить, что пользователь закрыл окно?

Comment: Вопрос общий, окно чего? Браузера? Проводника?

Comment: Поправил комментарий.

Comment: document.getElementById('file').onchange = function() {
    alert('hi');
}; Проще чем я думал

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, событий на такой случай не предусмотрено, но если этот инпут у вас один на странице, то можно поиграться с блюром/фокусом самой страницы. Для нотификашек пойдёт, но что-то серьёзное на таком коде лучше не строить.

```js
let log=document.querySelector('div'),
res
window.addEventListener('blur',()=>{
  res=false
  log.textContent='User choosing some file...'
})
document.querySelector('#uploadfile').addEventListener('change',()=>{
  res=true
  log.textContent='File was chosen!'
})
window.addEventListener('focus',()=>{
  if(res) return
  log.textContent='Got cancelation :('
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="uploadfile" />
<div></div>
```